# what is the difference between 'make after make clean' and just 'make'?

Tags: makefile

there are C files in a directory and I have a makefile.
I usually use makefile to compile.
I have been wandering the role of the 'make clean'
'make clean' is just to remove files.
Though I didn't use 'make clean', t
he error and warning was shown up when there were something wrong.
I cannot realize why I need to use 'make clean' whenever I change the source file.

Comment: It depends entirely on the contents of the makefile. If the dependencies are not set up correctly, or something else has touched a target file after its prerequisites were updated, `make` may not know the target needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: With perfect dependency graph in makefile it isn't necessary. But world isn't perfect, and many dependencies may be omitted (accidentally or on purpose - e.g. don't tracking system headers to reduce time wasted - this headers very rarely updated anyway). Clean build ensures that everything is built with latest versions of dependable files.

Answer (score 3):

**make** is a utility is to determine automatically which pieces of a large program need to be recompiled, and issue the commands to recompile them.

To prepare to use make, you must write a file called the makefile that describes the relationships among files in your program, and the states the commands for updating each file.

Once a suitable makefile exists, each time you change some source files, this simple shell command:

```
make
```

suffices to perform all necessary recompilations. The make program uses the makefile data base and the last-modification times of the files to decide which of the files need to be updated.

We generally use `make clean` as a generic way to tell clean up the code.ie; remove all the compiled object files from the source code. You can name it as anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

It's convention only. The convention is that `clean` will return you to a state where *all* you have is the "source" files. In other words, it gets rid of everything that can be built from something else (objects, executables, listings and so on).

So `make clean ; make` is expected to build *everything* from scratch. And, in fact, you'll often find a rule like:

```
rebuild: clean all
```

which will do both steps for you.

You should *never* have to do a `clean` unless you're wanting to (for example) copy just the source files somewhere. If you have to do so after editing a file, then your `Makefile` is not set up correctly.

And, if you `make` and get an error, you should get exactly the same error if you subsequently `make` without fixing said error.